# How can I run delegated method inside IBAction?

Tags: ios, swift, delegates

I have some methods in second view controller. I access them through delegate - inside func buttonSender. Main goal is to pass currentTitle of a button as an argument to a viewController.addNewMessage. What is the best way to do this?

ChatViewController:

```
protocol ReactToButtons {
    func buttonSender(viewController: MyChatViewController)
}


class MyChatViewController: ChatViewController{

    var delegate: ReactToButtons?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        delegate!.buttonSender(self)

    }
}
```

ContainerViewController:

```
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController, ReactToButtons {
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let myVC = segue.destinationViewController as! MyChatViewController
        myVC.delegate = self
    }

    func buttonSender(viewController: MyChatViewController) {
        viewController.addNewMessage(/*HERE GOES CURRENT TITLE*/)
    }

    @IBAction func leftButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let currentTitle = sender.currentTitle!

    }
```

Comment: You could write `@IBAction func leftButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {` to use any button methods.

Comment: Well it's not the case. I have some methods in second view controller. I access them through delegate - inside func buttonSender. Main goal is to pass currentTitle of a button as an argument to a viewController.addNewMessage

Comment: can't you modify the delegate method signature to include currentTitle as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have change my answer to suit your code

```
class ContainerViewController: UIViewController, ReactToButtons {
    var delegate: MyChatViewController!
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        let myVC = segue.destinationViewController as! MyChatViewController
        myVC.delegate = self
    }

    func buttonSender(viewController: MyChatViewController) {
    delegate = viewController
    }

    @IBAction func leftButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
        let currentTitle = sender.currentTitle!
        delegate!.addNewMessage(currentTitle)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really understand this answer. I have already `protocol ReactToButtons { func buttonSender(viewController: SecondViewController)}` and the class SecondViewController is like `var delegate: ReactToButtons?`, in viewDidLoad `delegate!.buttonSender(self)`.  Why should I create here another protocol?

Comment: @loup4 I see it, in your code, the containerViewController need a variable to save the buttonSender and then call it in your IBAction

Comment: @loup4 Actually you can simply let the MyChatViewController become the delegate of containerViewController, and call the delegate in your IBAction directly